# System.Net.Mail.MailAddress throws FormatException in VS2010 but not in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Code I used :

```
System.Net.Mail.MailAddress address = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("testî╥@mail.com");
```

The same code when excecuted from VS2010, throws FormatException. But when executed from VS2012, it doesn't throw any exception.

Stack Trace :

```
 at System.Net.Mime.MailBnfHelper.ReadMailAddress(String data, Int32& offset, String& displayName)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.ParseValue(String address)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding)
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address)
   at HP.Imaging.Wjp.AppCommon.EmailManager.EmailAddress.TryParse(String addressString, MailAddress& address) in ..\EmailAddress.cs:line 325
```

I could not find reason for this issue. Please help me finding solution.

Comment: You're talking about different versions of VS but what .NET versions are you targeting in each case?  is it the same project with the same .NET version?